# How to call a managed bean method via polling mechanism?

Tags: ajax, jsf

what i need is some kind of mechanism for executing a method from a managed bean in defined time intervals...so, basically i would need the poll tag from apache trinidad:

```
<tr:poll interval="5000" pollListener="#{myManagedBean.doPoll}" id="pollComponent"/>
```

But: We don't have the Trinidad implementation in our project and also are not able to include it in the current project stage. All we have is the MyFaces 2.0.6. implementation of JSF 2.

I already succeeded in writing a composite component that updates a particular field in a defined time interval as it is outlined in this article:

http://jsfatwork.irian.at/book_de/ajax.html#!idx:/ajax.html:6.4.2.

This example does nothing else than updating an output text containing the current time.

But what i really need to do is not to simply update a field but to also call a method containing some business logic.

Is there any way to achieve this with MyFaces and some 'hand made' composite components?

Is it possible to adjust the ajaxPoll component from the jsf-at-work tutorial above in a way, that it is able to execute a particular managed bean method?

Thanks in advance for all hints!

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest (and hackiest) you could submit a hidden form

```
<h:form id="poll" style="display:none">
    <h:commandLink id="link">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.poll}" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

with this JS

```
document.getElementById('poll:link').onclick();
```

Comment: Hm...ok, i don't really like using hidden forms and things like this but at least, this is a possible solution which does not require to introduce new technologies to our project.

Thanks a lot, BalusC!